# jQuery DOM manipulation not working in IE or Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, cross-browser, dom-manipulation

I have problems with the jQuery functions `prepend()` and `after()` which don't execute as expected in Safari or IE. Still no warning is to be seen in either of the developer tools. This piece of code works fine in both Chrome and Firefox.

What I am trying (and succeded) to accomplish is to sort a couple of rows through jQuery. The first element in the array will be moved as the first child of the `#tbody` element and the rest will be sorted after each other.

```
var $previousCountry = null;
var group_id = "A";
for (var i = 0; i < countries.length; i++) {
    var $country = $('#trcountry-' + countries[i].id);
    if (i === 0) {
        $('#tbody-' + group_id).prepend($country); //Problem 1
    }
    else {
        $previousCountry.after($country); //Problem 2
    }
    $previousCountry = $country;
}
```

Example HTML code:

```
<table>
    <tbody id="tbody-A">
        <tr id="trcountry-3"><td></td></tr> <!-- In fact a lot of td:s -->
        <tr id="trcountry-2"><td></td></tr>
        <tr id="trcountry-1"><td></td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Strangely enough I was able to execute the same piece of code - 
`$('#tbody-A').prepend('#trcountry-1');` - through the developer tools of all four browsers and it was successful every time.

What can cause this issue?

Comment: Please share the relevant HTML.

Comment: Where do you get `group_id` from?

Comment: @MMM I guess your question is relevant. `group_id` is set earlier and contains a letter depending on a user choice. But I know it isn't a part of the problem. `group_id` always gives the expected outcome. Edited question for clarity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figured it out. And I feel somewhat ashamed..

The problem was that my sort function was not correctly set up, which led to Safari and IE giving me unsorted data - thus the prepending was done in the exact same order as it was before, leading me to the assumption that the DOM manipulation went wrong.

Lesson learned.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're already using jquery, you could try using the tablesorter plugin. I've used it oftenly. Pretty much all you have to do is include the plugin and make the following api call:

```
$(document).ready(function() 
    { 
        $("#myTable").tablesorter(); 
    } 
);
```

Url: http://tablesorter.com/docs/#Demo

Comment: Nice plugin, but it's not the kind of solution I need. I don't want the clients to sort the table, I want them to predict the outcome of some football games and then letting my script sort the table depending on points every team gained.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.